# ios - UI does not update after swipe back if navigation controller has only 1 viewcontroller

Tags: ios

**viewControllerA** : `rootViewController` of `navigationController`

**viewControllerB** : will be pushed into `viewControllerA`'s `navigationController`

1. In viewControllerA's `viewDidLoad`,
set `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate`

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

2-1. push any `viewControllerB`. After `viewControllerB`'s view is appear, swipe back => `viewControllerB` will be pop, `viewControllerA` will be appear again (OK)

2-2. On `viewControllerA` is `topViewController`, swipe back (nothing change because there is no more `viewController` in `navigationController`)

=> (problem!!) then push controllerB, I expect controllerB's view will be appear but there is nothing change and every tap event does not works.

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove this line ?

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

I don't think it is necessary if you correctly push your controller using the navigation controller